# " was to have momentarily believed"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The parallel has been invoked more than once in discussion of Heidegger, **the implication being that his tragicomic error was to have momentarily believed that philosophy could guide politics**, especially the gutter politics of National Socialism.

I would like to ask whether it is possible to rewrite the bold passage that I don't fully understand in this way: the implication is that his tragicomic error rests in the fact that he was supposed to believe that philosophy could guide politics… I am not sure if the original passage expresses modality ("was to have believed") or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The parallel has been invoked more than once in discussion of Heidegger, the implication being that his tragicomic error was to have momentarily believed that philosophy could guide politics, especially the gutter politics of National Socialism.

Heidegger commited an error. What kind of error? He for a moment believed that philosophy can guide politics.

Thus, his error **was** [to have momentarily believed][that philosophy could guide politics].

The verb **was** here means **equaled**. Or, hmm... "consisted in":

> His error **consisted in** momentarily believing that philosophy could guide politics.